# Struts2 access ActionContext from jsp using property tag

Tags: java, struts2, actioncontext

I have been looking up this information for a while, but does not seem like there is much online.

To make it simple, how do we access the `ActionContext` through the `<s:property/>` tag?

Basically I want to get the `com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext.locale` (current locale)

I tried all these, but none seems to work

```
<s:property value="#com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext.locale"/>
<s:property value="${#com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext.locale}"/>
<s:property value="%{#com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext.locale}"/>
```

and more combinations of these.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `locale.toString()`?

```
Locale: <s:property value='locale.toString()'/>
```

**Edit**

As you want the value from `ActionContext` put this in your `action`:

```
public class FooAction extends ActionSupport {
    ...
    private String locale; // TODO: Getters and setters
    ...

    @Override
    public String execute () {
        ...
        locale = ActionContext.getContext().getLocale().toString();
        ...
    }
}
```

And then in your jsp you can access to the `locale` attribute with `<s:property>`.

```
<s:property value="locale"/>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I am tring to get the value from com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext.locale under action Context or in simple jsp <%=request.getLocale()%>.

The one you provided me would get the one in the value stack instead. Any clue how to get the other value?

Comment: The locale.toString() also must be used if you want to check it in the s:if test="%{locale.toString() == 'fa_IR'.

Answer (score 2):

The more direct method would be to say:

```
<s:property value="@com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext@getContext().locale"/>
```

For this to work static method invocation will need to be enabled in struts.xml

```
<struts>
  <constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true"/>
  ...
</struts>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it as:

```
<%=session.getAttribute("WW_TRANS_I18N_LOCALE") %>
```

This will get the locale directly from session